# google maps V3 bindDom equivalent?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We're migrating from the Google V2 maps API and I've had some trouble converting this line to  V3:

```
GEvent.bindDom(this.DOMItem, 'mousedown', this, this._customFunction);
```

I know about `google.maps.event.addDomListener` but is there a way to pass it the `this` parameter, as bindDom had in V2?  Otherwise our custom function can't access the object that created the binding.  That object has properties in it we need in the custom function.  Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just use javascript's `call` method.

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(this.DOMItem, 'mousedown', function() { this._customFunction.call(this); });
```

In the scope of `_customFunction`, `this` will be set to whatever you pass as the first argument to `call`.

Comment: I was thinking about that, thanks.  I added a 'context' property to DOMItem that held `this`, and used it in the custom function, but your way is cleaner. (Though I do wish I knew why google removed that API function or its equivalent between V2-->V3...)